# Insert statement Into SQL Server throws error, but inserts record anyway?

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I've got an Insert system where a user fills in several fields, which is caught by a PHP script and then inserted into the database.

On the outset, it seems fine as it inserts the record, however when I check the result to make sure it's actually gone in, `$result` returns false, meaning the page doesn't redirect, am I missing something?

```
$Prefix = $_POST['Prefix'];
$Clients = $_POST['Clients'];
$SiteName = $_POST['SiteName'];
$EndUserName = $_POST['EndUser'];
$RateType = $_POST['RateType'];
$Description = $_POST['Description'];
$QuoteStateID = '1';
$Revision = '1';
$Number = '-1';
$CreateDate = date("Y-m-d");


$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "Insert Into Quotations (QPrefix, QClientName, QEndUserSite, QEndUserName, RateTypeID, QDescription, QuoteStateID, QRevision, QNumber, QCreateDate, QCreateUser) 
Values ('$Prefix','$Clients','$SiteName','$EndUserName','$RateType','$Description', '$QuoteStateID','$Revision','$Number','$CreateDate','$CreateUser')");

echo $CreateUser.'</br>'.$Prefix.'</br>'.$Clients.'</br>'.$SiteName.'</br>'.$EndUserName.'</br>'.$RateType.'</br>'.$Description.'</br>'.$QuoteStateID.'</br>'.$Revision.'</br>'.$Number.'</br>'.$CreateDate;

if($result)
{       
        echo "record added successfully";
        redirect();
}
elseif(($errors = sqlsrv_errors()) != null)
{
    foreach( $errors as $error)
    {
        echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."\n";
        echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."\n";
        echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."\n";
    }
}
else{
    echo "nope";
}
```

The my error checking `elseif` throws out:

> SQLSTATE: 01000 code: 14243 message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Job 'SSISUpdateExcelQuotation' started successfully

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not an error :)

Comment: Well thats what my error catching threw out, still doesnt explain why $result comes back as false..

Comment: looks like you found a bug in php / sqlserver

Comment: So thats it? its a bug? Lol.

Comment: Is there any trigger on `Quotations` table? Looks like some user defined `RAISERROR` code exists in somewhere.